# Reset a table keeping the output values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where cells C1 to C3 (for example) are programmed with …

- C1: `=10-A1`
- C2: `=10-A2`
- C3: `=10-A3`

… respectively.

Through the week I'll change the values of A1, A2 and A3, but in the end of the week I want the column A clear and the column C with the last output values of the week, for example, if the last value I put in A1 was `3`, the cell C1 will show me `7`, the next week the cell A1 will be clear and the cell C1 will still have the programation, but starting with the value `7`, not `10`.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: How would you do it in a workbook manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your data into something like the following

[image]

And then in the end of the week run a code to start the next week:
The code copies the current week into the last week values and clears current week.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StartNextWeek()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("week")
        'copy current to last week
        .Range("B2:B4").Value = .Range("A2:A4").Value

        'clear current week
        .Range("A2:A4").Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

So in the next week you would start with

[image]